# Android Studio emulator minimum CPU requirement

Tags: android, android-studio

I used to have `HP Pro Book 4320s`(2010 laptop) and I downloaded `Android Studio` with no problems. However when I tried to run emulator, `Android Studio` said CPU is too old to support emulator. So, what is minimum requirement for emulator?
Also if you can't run emulator, would real device be able to run an app regardless CPU or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run the emulator, you need to have a CPU that supports HAXM, Intel VT-x, or AMD-V for virtualization. Processors like i3,i5,i7 and recent AMD processors have that support.

Yes, you can run the app on a physical device regardless of the CPU.

If getting access to a physical device is challenging, then I suggest checking out the [Firebase Testlab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/) . You can test your app in the cloud and see if it runs, quite cool.

Comment: Thank for clear explanation. If you run an app on real device, 4GB RAM would be survivable? Running on emulator would not be enough with 4GB RAM. What about real device? Do you know by any chance?

Comment: 4gb is fine for running the app on a real device. However, you will notice a reduction in the amount of time it takes to run the app if you have more RAM. 4gb is not enough for the emulator though. You could try to run it, but it will slow down your pc.

Answer (score 1):

**Please have a look of below content according to android official documentation. I hope it will help you**

The Android Emulator has additional requirements beyond the basic system requirements for Android Studio:

SDK Tools 26.1.1 or higher
64-bit processor
Windows: CPU with UG (unrestricted guest) support
HAXM 6.2.1 or later (HAXM 7.2.0 or later recommended)
The use of hardware acceleration has additional requirements on Windows and Linux:

Intel processor on Windows or Linux: Intel processor with support for Intel VT-x, Intel EM64T (Intel 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality
AMD processor on Linux: AMD processor with support for AMD Virtualization (AMD-V) and Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (SSSE3)
AMD processor on Windows: Android Studio 3.2 or higher and Windows 10 April 2018 release or higher for Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) functionality
To work with Android 8.1 (API level 27) and higher system images, an attached webcam must have the capability to capture 720p frames.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator